# Creating /likes connection for FB

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a question related to Facebook Graph API. On [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/) it says: "**Like the given object (if it has a */likes connection*)**"

However, I was not able to find instructions for making that ***/likes connection***

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have to “make” it – some FB objects *have* a `likes` connection, f.e. the `post`, `photo` or `comment` object – and those you can like via API.

Look at the descriptions of the individual objects to find out whether or not they have that connection.